# Why one root is missing for this equation?

Tags: equation-solving, functions

I solved this symbolic equation and it has 3 roots.

```
IN1 = Solve[Sqrt[2 x/ a2] ==  Sqrt[2 x/ a1] + x*b, x]
OUT1 = {{x -> 0}, {x -> (2 (a1 - 2 Sqrt[a1] Sqrt[a2] + a2))/(
   a1 a2 b^2)}, {x -> (2 (Sqrt[a1] + Sqrt[a2])^2)/(a1 a2 b^2)}}
```

If I subsitute `a2 = 1, a1 = 4, b = 10` I got the numerical values of the roots above as `0, 1/200, 9/200`. However, if I substitute `a2 = 1, a1 = 4, b = 10` into the initial equation and solve it I got only two roots.

```
IN2= Solve[Sqrt[2 x/1] ==  Sqrt[2 x/ 4] + x*10, x]
OUT2 = {{x -> 0}, {x -> 1/200}}
```

what is wrong here?

Comment: Don't you get a `Solutions may not be valid for all values of parameters.` message?

Comment: @CarlWoll I don't see that warning.

Comment: I suppose that message must be new in 12.3 or so. Basically, the process that Solve uses can introduce parasitic roots, and that is what happens here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

sol1 = Solve[Sqrt[2 x/a2] == Sqrt[2 x/a1] + x*b, x] /. {a2 -> 1, a1 -> 4, 
   b -> 10}

(* Solve::nongen: Solutions may not be valid for all values of parameters.

{{x -> 0}, {x -> 1/200}, {x -> 9/200}} *)
```

Check the solutions

```
Sqrt[2 x/a2] == Sqrt[2 x/a1] + x*b /. {a2 -> 1, a1 -> 4, b -> 10} /. sol1

(* {True, True, False} *)
```

The third solution is an extraneous solution (i.e, does not satisfy the equation)

```
sol2 = Solve[
  Sqrt[2 x/a2] == Sqrt[2 x/a1] + x*b /. {a2 -> 1, a1 -> 4, b -> 10}, x]

(* {{x -> 0}, {x -> 1/200}} *)
```

From the documentation "Solve deals primarily with linear and polynomial equations" Use [`Reduce`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reduce.html)

```
sol3 = Reduce[Sqrt[2 x/a2] == Sqrt[2 x/a1] + x*b, x] /. {a2 -> 1, a1 -> 4, 
   b -> 10}

(* Reduce::useq: The answer found by Reduce contains unsolved equation(s) {0==(-Sqrt[x]-Sqrt[a2] Sqrt[Power[<<2>>] x])/Sqrt[a2],0==(Sqrt[x]-Sqrt[a2] Sqrt[Power[<<2>>] x])/Sqrt[a2],0==-((2 (-Sqrt[2]+<<1>>))/(a2 b)),0==-<<1>>,<<1>>,0==<<1>>/<<1>>,0==<<1>>/(Sqrt[a1] a2 b),0==<<1>>/(a1 a2 b)}. A likely reason for this is that the solution set depends on branch cuts of Wolfram Language functions.

x == 0 || x == 1/200 *)

sol4 = Reduce[
  Sqrt[2 x/a2] == Sqrt[2 x/a1] + x*b /. {a2 -> 1, a1 -> 4, b -> 10}, x]

(* x == 0 || x == 1/200 *)
```